# Why it is storing just two characters instead of 4?

Tags: c

This is my code:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    int main() 
    {

        char a[10][10];

        int i,n,m,j;

        n=2;
        m=2;


        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            for(j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
                scanf("%c",&a[i][j]);
            }

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
                printf("%c",a[i][j]);
            }
        }

    }
```

Output:

a b c d

a b

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 3.965 s
Press any key to continue.

Comment: I don't know what you asking please update your question in clearly.

Comment: `scanf(" %c"` <- note the space before the %c.

Comment: @RetiredNinja thank you for your help, now i clearly understood it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they are storing and two of them is the space. That's why you don't see them.

Try this and you will understand

```
printf("[%c]",a[i][j]);
```

To solve the issue you can do this

```
scanf(" %c",&a[i][j]);
```

This consumes the white space character between the two character input.

From standard:- 7.21.6.2

> Input white-space characters (as specified by the isspace function)
>   **are skipped, unless the specification includes** a [, **c**, or n specifier

and this

> A directive composed of **white-space character(s) is executed by
>   reading input up to the first non-white-space character** (which remains
>   unread), or until no more characters can be read. The directive never
>   fails.

Comment: @LalitVerma.: Yes because `' '` matches it. scanf is kind of like parser. Sorry for late reply.

Comment: @LalitVerma.: I have mentioned the relevant sections of the standard explainign both

Comment: thank you @coderredoc for clearing this doubt, now i understood.